# Xcode 6 GM seed unable to boot ios simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6gm

I am trying to run my application with X-code 6 GM seed (Latest X-code version not beta) & IOS 8 simulator is not working every time it say 'unable to boot ios simulator'.

I already tried below given link solution but all goes vain

[not works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023029/error-opening-ios-simulator-with-ios-8-beta-version-unable-to-boot-the-ios-sim)
[Not works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033417/unable-to-run-app-in-simulator-xcode-beta-6-ios-8)

Any one know else face this problem or have any solution then please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it still not working?

Answer (score 1):

"unable to boot ios simulator" is a generic error for when the simulated runtime's bootstrap server (launchd_sim) does not respond within a certain time period.  It usually responds in less than 1/100th of this time.  This can occur if something is preventing launchd_sim from running.  Check for crash logs in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports or /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports

This is most often caused by the setting of DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES.  Do you have DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES set?  To find out, open Terminal.app and run 'echo $DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES'

dyld_sim will attempt to log that it is ignoring the library because it is a host dylib and not a simulator dylib.  It uses logging routines provided by the host's dyld to do this, but on Mavericks, dyld has a bug and will crash.  This is fixed in Yosemite's dyld.

Try unsetting DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES or upgrading to Yosemite if that is the case.  If that is not the case, I'm curious what your crash logs reveal.