# Simulator not working and showing the error message "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator"

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, ios10

I am using xcode 7.3.1 version, when I run my project it will show the error "Unable to boot the iOS Simulator". I did reinstalled entire Mac OS and Xcode, I have lost lot of time to fix the issue. Still I can't run my project in simulator. I have installed Xcode 8 for testing app in iOS 10 and reinstalled once completed the tesing. Its happened without any other change in my project, Please anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023029/error-opening-ios-simulator-with-ios-8-beta-version-unable-to-boot-the-ios-sim

Comment: I can't run simulator after reinstallation of OS and Xcode