# Unable to boot the simulator, launchd failed to respond Xcode 10.0

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator

I'm new to iOS development.

I downloaded Xcode 10.1 from AppStore but it had some errors at startup and couldn't show up. So I downgraded Xcode to version 10.0 (10A255) from Apple official downloads. IDE works fine but now I can't start simulator. I've tried every possible solution on the internet for hours. Here is the logs:

> CoreSimulatorService[393] : com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService 581.2 starting.
>
> com.apple.ibtool[479] : Spawning processes in an unbooted
>   state without setting kSimDeviceSpawnStandalone is deprecated.
>
> com.apple.ibtool[478] : Spawning processes in an unbooted
>   state without setting kSimDeviceSpawnStandalone is deprecated.
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.PowerManagement.control: launch_sim_register_endpoint:
>   0xfffffecc
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.SystemConfiguration.configd_host:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0xfffffecc
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.audio.coreaudiod: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0xfffffecc
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.SystemConfiguration.PPPController:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0xfffffecc
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.audio.audiohald: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.coreservices.lsuseractivity.simulatorsupport:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.SystemConfiguration.configd: launch_sim_register_endpoint:
>   0x44e
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.FSEvents: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   PurpleFBTVOutServer: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   IndigoHIDRegistrationPort: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   PurpleFBServer: launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Could not register service
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.host.bootstrap_port:
>   launch_sim_register_endpoint: 0x44e
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=60 "Operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable
>   to boot the Simulator., NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to
>   respond.}
>
> CoreSimulatorService[393] : Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=60 "Operation timed out" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable
>   to boot the Simulator., NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to
>   respond.}    CoreSimulatorService[393] : Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=60 "Operation timed out"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to boot the Simulator.,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=launchd failed to respond.}

What can I do?

Comment: I have completely same as your issues in macOS 10.13.6 and Xcode 10.0, 10.1 suddenly. Was it solved?

Comment: @Kueiapp I upgraded or downgraded Xcode an that solved it. I don't remeber the version, it was a while ago, sorry.

Comment: follow this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023029/error-opening-ios-simulator-with-ios-8-beta-version-unable-to-boot-the-ios-sim

Answer (score 74):

Goto 'About this mac' -> 'Storage' -> 'Developer'. Delete **Xcode Caches**. Then try again!
[image]

Comment: Great! This solved my problem! Xcode 15 failed to start simulator iPhone 8 Plus.

Comment: Great! This is probably useful in other tricky situations too. Good to have when other solutions doesn't work.

Comment: Works great! One thing: on my Macbook, Apple Icon => 'About this Mac' doesn't display a Storage section. However, you can find it in System Setting => General => Storage => 'Storage Settings' button

Answer (score 12):

In my case clearing derived data helped.
You can do it like this:

Open Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data (Click the little arrow) -> Delete the folder.

Answer (score 11):

In my case

```
Unable to boot the Simulator.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 60
Failure Reason: launchd failed to respond.
```

Was fixed by restarting my wifi router which was playing up.

Answer (score 10):

In Xcode 14.2 cleaning the build folder resolved this issue for me.

```
 Product -> Clean Build Folder
```

Answer (score 5):

For my `Xcode 15.3` and `Sonoma 14.4` helped the removing of simulator's `Caches` folder at `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches`

1. Open `Finder`.
2. Execute `⌘ Cmd + ↑ Shift + G` (go to folder).
3. Execute `⌘ Cmd + V` (pastes copied text) of copied `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator` path.

P.S. If not helped than try to remove `DerivedData` of your project at `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 1):

In my case i have to drag the simulator to the trash bin the i relaunch again and it open

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click on the simulator icon
2. Click on "Options".
3. Click on "Show in Finder"

When the finder is open

4. Right-click on the icon again
5. Then click "Move to bin"

After deleting the simulator

6. Go to your computer bin and restore it

It must work.

You're welcome

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing the last update to the SO

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, sad to say but restarting my Mac actually fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

For me this happened and was gone after I restarted the mac but after sometime it came back again, some people are telling to restart but for me it came back again so i don't think so that is a permanent solution. So currently what solved it immediately was what's mentioned in the first answer i.e deleting the Xcode Cache by:

clicking on apple logo -> System Settings -> Search Storage Settings -> click on more info "i" icon of Developer button -> Select xcode cache and delete -> restart xcode and then run. Thank you!

ps: I am using Apple M1 Pro with Sonoma 14.0 macOS and Xcode 15.0.1