# Xcode 15: Unable to boot the Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, ios-simulator

I was able to run iOS simulator fine with Xcode 14 and my Mac recently updated the latest version of Xcode which is 15 then I'm no longer able to boot a device from its new simulator.

I did try many different ways collected from many sources but no avail. Here are the few things that I already tried and none of them worked for me:

- Remove all the Xcode caches from Storage either from cli or UI as suggested from here: [Flutter: XCode error "Unable to boot the Simulator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72229589/flutter-xcode-error-unable-to-boot-the-simulator)
- Try all possible answers from here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667088
- Follow this article: https://medium.com/@liwp.stephen/my-solution-to-solve-unable-to-boot-the-ios-simulator-39bbb4aad100
- Reinstall Xcode with removing all related files: [https://byby.dev/uninstall-xcode#:~:text=Delete%20old%20simulators%20and%20devices,moving%20them%20to%20the%20Trash](https://byby.dev/uninstall-xcode#:%7E:text=Delete%20old%20simulators%20and%20devices,moving%20them%20to%20the%20Trash).
- Downgrade Xcode to v14

**BTW here is the full log that I collected as run it via cli:**

```bash
xcrun simctl boot 39C3D624-968A-49F7-A155-AC9AC1A81B52
```

```
Unable to boot the Simulator.
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 60
Failure Reason: launchd failed to respond.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-09-26 04:06:49 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = "_IDEInstalliPhoneSimulatorWorker";
    Session = "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.AC5CB945-2257-4E8C-AA61-ABC5AC147D84";
}
--
Failed to start launchd_sim: could not bind to session, launchd_sim may have crashed or quit responding
Domain: com.apple.SimLaunchHostService.RequestError
Code: 4
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone16,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "17.0 (21A328)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "348.1";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.2.4";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 23640;
    "operation_errorCode" = 60;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = "_IDEInstalliPhoneSimulatorWorker";
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator17.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--

System Information

macOS Version 13.6 (Build 22G120)
Xcode 15.0 (22265) (Build 15A240d)
Timestamp: 2023-09-26T11:06:49+07:00
```

I will appreciate any help!

**Update on 28th Sep 2023**

I just upgraded macOS to the latest version v14 with name (Sonoma)and tried to remove all caches again but still no avail :(

**Update on 29th Sep 2023**

I also tried to download 3 last iOS versions and interestingly the iOS 15 works for me while none of the 2 others still work.

**Update on 16th Nov 2023 (important)**

I just re-open the simulator and **somehow it suddenly works automatically without doing anything**, not sure what has been updated from Apple makes it working. Anyway, this is a good news and I guess Apple might have been aware of the bug and released a fix silently

Comment: Have you tried removing the derived data? .../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: Yes I deleted everything that I know which contains this one too

Comment: same error, same steps taken, same result... 
I'm using the last intel based macboo pro, all my collegues already have M1 or M2 macs and don't have issues... I hope it has nothing to to with the architecture

Comment: hmm it doesn't sound like to happen to everyone since my Mac is the M1 one

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm using an M1 MacBook Pro so it appears to impact both architectures.

Comment: From the logs "device_model" = "iPhone16,1"; Shouldn't it be iPhone 15. How did you create iPhone 16 simulator? I don't see that option in Xcode 15.

Comment: I think you need to download the iOS 17 runtime then it comes up with loads of new added devices automatically

Comment: check this, maybe this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/77192573/11762907

Answer (score 106):

Here is what worked for me. I am using Xcode Version 15.2

**Solution**

1. Open System Settings
2. Search Storage >> Developer
3. Delete Xcode caches, project archives and project build data

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me on Xcode 15.2. Didn't have to delete Project Archives, just the other two.

Comment: This answer worked for me with Simulator version 15.0.1

Comment: In my case I only deleted Xcode Caches. And my Simulator was reborn.

Comment: This might help momentarilary, but I expect the issue would recur as soon as the shared cache is recreated and before it is scanned.  The issue should resolve itself after waiting a few minutes for the system to scan the shared cache, or you can update to Xcode 15.3 Beta 2 or later which avoids using the dyld shared cache until it has been scanned.

Answer (score 62):

I fixed this by opening XCode, then Xcode -> Settings -> Platforms. For me iOS 17.0 was not downloaded. After downloading and restarting my computer, the Simulator launched again.

Comment: This fixed my issue! Cheers!

Comment: Both iOS 16 and 17 runtimes didn't work for me, interestingly iOS 15 works! No ideas what's going on and probably wait for the fix from Apple

Comment: Yep! That fixed it for me! Thanks

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't even need to restart. (MacBook Pro M1 Max)

Comment: Worked like a charm, no restart.

Comment: That fixed it. It's absolutely shocking that apple would release an update that is so broken with no error, but thank you!

Comment: I had iOS 17 installed, but it worked after reinstalling it. This answer inspired the "reinstallation". Thanks @Walter

Comment: OMG you saved my life. Spent several hours wondering why it suddenly stopped working..... thanks. Apple

Comment: I was thrown off by having iOS 17.0.1 installed but downloading exactly 17.0 is what was needed.  Then I had a whole list of simulators to choose from.

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue I solved it by going to "About this Mac -> Storage -> Manage -> Developer" then by deleting Xcode cache. After that I was able to run my app in simulator.

Comment: @Hassy Have you tried the solution which I gave?

Comment: Yes I did deleted the Xcode cache and it worked.

Comment: This solved my issue after deleting almost everything related to simulator and adding it up again. Thank zou so much!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and error log.

What worked for me was:

1. Go to ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator
2. Delete all folders inside.
3. When you now run a simulator, it will say it's not found/missing (since we deleted them).
4. Go to manage run destinations, delete the simulator(in my case it was iPhone 13, iOS 15), click a plus sign, name your new simulator and add a new one. voilá! now you can use the new one for running the app.

Comment: I did try this way too and it didn't work in case of iOS 16 & 17 anyway

Comment: This worked for me specially the last part. Go to managed run Destinations and try adding a new simulator using plus sign. Thanks

Comment: Just Installed Xcode 15.2 and same thing happened to me as above. This worked for me.

Comment: Where can you find "manage run destinations"? @malaki1974

Comment: @gb992 You can find it by clicking on the simulator name in the center top of xcode, and on the bottom of that list you'll find Manage run destinations! Hope that helps.

Comment: I did that and was necessary to run this after: "xcrun simctl delete unavailable"
it was necessary to clean the list on xcode and install new simulator.

Comment: Oh no!  Don't do this, especially if CoreSimulatorService is running.  This will lead to more problems because CoreSimulatorService will expect to find those devices on disk but they won't be there.

Answer (score 5):

Just run this in the terminal:

```
xcrun simctl shutdown all && xcrun simctl erase all
```

to reset the iPhone Simulator

Comment: Tried this. Didn't help.

Comment: I would not expect this to help.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting caches should not be necessary here.  I expect that will just cause the issue to recur later.

There are a few causes we've identified for this issue:

1. There is a performance issue reading from the simulator runtime disk images which can result in boot triggering that watchdog timer, especially if I/O is competing with the process that is generating the dyld shared cache. This performance issue has been addressed in macOS 14.4 Beta and later.
2. The dyld_sim shared cache fails to map into a process within the watchdog timer because it was just recently created and is still being scanned by the system.  Deleting the cache will momentarily address this problem, but you would hit it again the next time the cache is created.  Waiting ~2 minutes should allow the scan to complete.  Additionally, if you update to Xcode 15.3 Beta 2 or later (released last week), we now avoid attempting to use the cache until that scan is complete.
3. If an XProtect update is installed (which happens ~weekly), that will invalidate the cached scan results for the dyld shared cache, and you will hit the issue on subsequent boots.  As of the currnet version of Xcode (15.3), there is no workaround for this, but we hope to deliver one soon.

I recommend that users facing this issue please update to macOS 14.4 Beta or later and Xcode 15.3 Beta 2 or later to get the mitigations that are available.

If you still see this issue, please collect the following tarballs and attach them to a report at http://bugreport.apple.com:

```
xcrun simctl diagnose
sudo sysdiagnose
```

Also, if you're able, please enable debug logging via:

```
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator DebugLogging -bool YES
```

You can remove the debug logging later with:

```
defaults delete com.apple.CoreSimulator DebugLogging)
```

Note that we've had multiple reports of this issue over the past 6 months, but triage has been difficult in part because we have not been getting the logging requested above and by the time the reporter gets around to responding to the request, they are out of the problematic state (because it usually resolves on its own in a few minutes).  Please do not assume that someone else is providing the data. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to mitigate when I don't have the possibility to update macOS and Xcode? I think I'm running into this on hosted build runners and would love for this to work. @jeremy-huddleston-sequoia

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have destroyed the integration of the simulators, but you don’t need to do something with the Xcode cause they are separated totally.

### Solution

1. Open your Xcode
2. Manage Run Destination.
3. Find simulators matched your Identifier and delete it.
4. Create a new simulator with the same `deviceType` and `OS Version`.
5. Now you are able to boot it with a new identifier.

Comment: I did this way many times and even tried with fastlane way to recreate new devices but no luck in the end

Comment: @tmhao2005 Did you give the simulator permission to run in the Mac's Security & Privacy Settings ?

Comment: Does not work for me as well. At least my mac does not crash anymore now.
I deleted all derived data, everything in Developer (global and user) reinstalled my OSX (no clean install though), reinstaleld xcode and simulators... and still...
Xcode 14 and iOS 16 Simulators work fine, but not iOS 17

Comment: @Elevo I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: @tmhao2005 You can have a try to delete all iOS platform data and reinstall it. Steps: open Xcode -> Settings -> Platforms -> iOS 17.0(7.56GB in my mac) -> Delete(waiting) -> Get.

Comment: @tmhao2005 also checks this the same error as you https://stackoverflow.com/a/58918799/17771995

Comment: I downloaded different iOS runtime versions and confirmed none of those work :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case, in my case installing additional old Simulator (it was 16.4 sim runtime) solved the problem. After installing Sim 6.4 and rebooting my mac - voila, suddenly even 17'th Sim started working

Comment: I downloaded both iOS 16 and 17 and none of them worked for me

Comment: Oh good news that it appears to work with older version iOS 15

Comment: I was trying to run iOS 15 simulator on Xcode 15, and it's still giving me the same error, but mine was slightly different: `Unable to boot the simulator. Interrupted system call`

Comment: Same issue here with iOS 15 simulator. Did you find a fix marticztn?

Comment: @victorgson nope, still cannot run iOS 15 simulator on Xcode 15.0.1, what about you?

Comment: I can, just remove all xCode installations, run DevCleaner to clean all and do fresh install

Comment: It seems it cannot be done: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/741044

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.

I am using Xcode Version 15.0 (15A240d)

I double checked my registered devices under my apple developer account, I somehow had two different UUID's for the same MacBook Pro, so I checked the same one for my current MacBook and erased the wrong one, I quit Xcode and reopened then simulator worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having extremely long simluator launch times when I updated to Xcode 15 when it released. Downgrade to Xcode 14 helped, but after installing Sonoma on my MacBook Pro M1, unforunatelly, I was not able to use Xcode 14 anymore. And if you are still on macOS Ventura, my advice is to refrain from updating it so far. At least wait for new fixed versions of Xcode 15 to be released.

But if you don't want to downgrade both your macOS and Xcode, then try to use the next steps. They helped me but simulator does not work as smooth as it used to be.

1. Download iOS 16.4 simulator and create simulators with that version.
2. Delete default iOS 17 runtime simulators and recreate them.
3. Delete derived data (*Xcode -> Settings-> Locations -> Derived Data (Click the little arrow) -> Delete the folder*)

After these steps I was able to run simultators on my MacBook. But I have to say that the launch time of iOS 17 simulator and the apps takes quite more time, and it is still not very responsive and very laggy. You might also see that sometimes it takes forever to attach/install the app, and during this process simulator gets frozen and unresponsive. Restarting Simulator helps.

Didn't face any major issues using iOS 16.4 sim on Sonoma and Xcode 15, so I definetely recommend to use them now as they are smoother, faster and more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

It finally turned out, that in Xcode my User account was logged out, due to a password change I had made on my developer account, and my developer account needed an actualising for the devices after a renewal of my license.

Answer (score -1):

I also got this issue since updating to Xcode 15. When trying to implement [Walter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77258368/4958496) above, I found out that adding previous version of simulator (in my case, iOS 15.0) helps to fix the issue, now I can boot my simulator again. Add previous version Simulator by clicking + button on bottom left. No need to restart macbook, can use right away after installing.

[image: Add iOS 15.0 Simulator by clicking + button on bottom left]

Comment: Nope I think he missed the iOS 17 runtime and after had downloaded, it worked for him with this version. For us, it appears to work with only iOS 15 runtime at this stage

Answer (score -1):

I also had this issue (on Xcode 15.1).

For me the problem was the iOS version of the simulator. In the simulators list, each device was listed twice, once with iOS 17.0.1 and once with iOS 17.2.
It only worked when selecting a simulator with iOS 17.2.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had to update the MacOS ... It was saying that a Mac system update was available but I was ignoring it.   After completing the update the "unable to boot simulator." didn't show - instead the iOS emulator turned up.

Try updating your Mac : )