# iOS Emulator(XCode) won't launch

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When I try to launch iOS simulator via Terminal ("open -a simulator") or via XCode, Simulator icon just shows on Dock and it is not showing Iphone emulator. Simulator worked like two weeks ago normally, but then it stoppend.

I thoguth it was updating itself in background and i leaved laptop on for about 2 hours but still nothing, it is not showing emulator.

Comment: Having the same issues and following the thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77177016/xcode-15-unable-to-boot-the-simulator