# Unable to boot the simulator when Xcode update is available

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator, simulator, xcode15

### Issue with Xcode Simulator: Unable to Boot (when Xcode update is available)

#### Description

I'm encountering a persistent issue with the Xcode Simulator. Whenever a new Xcode update is available, the Simulator stops working, displaying an "Unable to boot the simulator" error.

It was working well until yesterday. The Xcode 15.2 became available 12 hours ago, and the simulator stopped working after that. Every time this has happened, the simulator did not work unless I updated the Xcode.

#### Details

- **IDE:** VS Code
- **Xcode Version:** 15.1 ( Update to 15.2 is available )
- **macOS Version:** Ventura 13.5.2
- **iOS Version:** 17.2
  [image]
- **Error Message:** "Unable to boot the simulator"

[image]

- **Steps Taken:**

  - Restarted the machine and Simulator
  - Ran `xcrun simctl shutdown all && xcrun simctl erase all`

Comment: I'm running Xcode 15.1 on macOS 13.6.3 and I have no issue starting any iOS 17.2 simulators. So this is not a general issue. How are you trying to start a simulator?

Comment: It was working fine for me until yesterday, but as the update 15.2 became available it stopped working. Usually, I start my simulator from `VS Code` and use the command `open -a simulator`.

Comment: I'm able to start the xcode though.

Comment: Can you run the simulator via Xcode? Your issue could be related to VS Code. You should update your question and describe that you are using VS Code and not Xcode to run the simulator.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it

Comment: @HangarRash Opening the simulator app from this directory worked.
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app`. 
I had also cleaned the Xcode caches before this.

Comment: Deleting the XCode cache was the solution for me. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77834086/2602848